# CDF of a convergent positive series

Tags: probability, limits, pointwise-convergence, cumulative-distribution-functions

Let $Y_0, Y_1, \ldots$ be an i.i.d. random sequence such that
$$ \mathbb{P}(Y_k = 0) \;=\; 1 - \mathbb{P}(Y_k = 1) \;=\; p \qquad \text{for each $k\ge 0$}. $$
I am interested in the following random sequences
$$ U_k = \prod_{i=0}^{k-1}\gamma^{Y_i} \theta^{1 - Y_i}, $$
$$ Q_n = \sum_{k=1}^n U_k, $$
where $0<\theta<1<\gamma$.

I have proved that $Q_\infty = \sum_{k=1}^\infty U_k$ converges a.s. when $p> \log \gamma/\log (\theta^{-1}\gamma)$. That means under this case, $Q_\infty$ is a random variable and it makes sense to consider its CDF (cumulative distribution function).

Let us use $F_n$ and $F_\infty$ to denote the CDFs of $Q_n$ and $Q_\infty$, respectively. I also proved that actually $F_n \downarrow F_\infty$ when $n\to\infty$. Now I am curious about what is exactly $F_\infty$. Can we have a beautiful explicit formula for it? Or can we have a tight lower bound of it?

I also use MATLAB to draw the pictures of $F_n$ as follows (I set $\gamma=2$, $\theta=0.5$, and $p=0.51$), but I can only have $n$ around 20 since the time of computing this $F_n$ is $\mathcal{O}(2^n)$.

Any comments are welcome.

[image]

Answer (score 0):

Suppose that $\gamma>\theta>0$. Noting that $X_i=\sum_{i=0}^{k-1} Y_i\sim\text{Binomial}(k,1-p)$ is the sum of $k$ independent and identically distributed $Y_{i}\sim\text{Bernoulli}(1-p)$ random variables, we have
\begin{align}
P(U_k\leq u)&=P\left(\gamma^{X_k} \theta^{k-X_k}\leq u\right),\\
&=P\left(X_k\leq \frac{k\ln\theta-\ln u}{\ln\theta-\ln\gamma}\right).\\
\end{align}
By the de Moivre–Laplace theorem, as $k\rightarrow\infty$, we have $X_k\sim\mathcal{N}(n(1-p),np(1-p))$ so that
\begin{align}
F_{U_{\infty}}(u)&=F_{X_{\infty}}\left(\frac{k\ln\theta-\ln u}{\ln\theta-\ln\gamma}\right),\text{ and }\\
p_{U_{\infty}}(u)&=F_{U_{\infty}}'(u),\\
&=\frac{1}{u\left(\ln\gamma-\ln\theta\right)}F_{X_{\infty}}'\left(\frac{k\ln\theta-\ln u}{\ln\theta-\ln\gamma}\right),\\
&\propto \frac{1}{u}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\frac{k\ln\theta-\ln u}{\ln\theta-\ln\gamma}-n(1-p)}{p(1-p)}\right)^2\right),\\
&\propto \frac{1}{u}\exp\left(-\frac{1}{2}\left(\frac{\left(\ln u-\left(n\ln\gamma-np\ln\gamma+np\ln\theta-n\ln\theta+k\ln\theta\right)\right)^2}{(np(1-p)(\ln\gamma-\ln\theta))^2}\right)^2\right),\\
\end{align}
and $U_{\infty}\sim\text{Lognormal}(n\ln\gamma-np\ln\gamma+np\ln\theta-n\ln\theta+k\ln\theta,np(1-p)(\ln\gamma-\ln\theta))$. Now, the PDF (or CDF) for the sum of $n$ independent and identically distributed lognormal random variables is a famously hard problem but, as a rule of thumb, it is approximately lognormal. See [here](https://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/238529/the-sum-of-independent-lognormal-random-variables-appears-lognormal) for the $n=2$ case.

As $n\rightarrow\infty$, we may incite CLT (since we have a defined mean and variance for $U_{\infty}$). I'm aware that you are interested in summing $U_k$ and not $U_{\infty}$ but your plot of the CDF tends towards something approx. lognormal and so I hope my argument will work anyway (if only in an asymptotic sense).

Comment: Thank you for your comment! But I found a problem in your idea, that is, all your "$n$" should be changed to "$k$", and we can have $U_k \sim \operatorname{Lognormal}(k(\ln \gamma - p \ln (\theta^{-1}\gamma)),  kp(1-p)(\ln \theta^{-1}\gamma)^2)$  as $k\to\infty$, which implies $U_k\to 0$. Although it is not the answer I want, thank you again!